# Eliminar las clases .d-md-block y d-none de Bootstrap 4 de carousel-caption desde Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

Quisiera eliminar las clases `.d-md-block` y `d-none` de Bootstrap 4 desde Angular. Necesito borrarlas porque el título del carrusel no es visible en dispositivos pequeños y porque encontré que es la solución a mi problema en este otro [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451739/bootstrap-4-carousel-caption-is-not-visible-on-small-devices). De hecho, ya probé borrándolas desde el inspector de elementos y funciona.
Cada vez que recargo la página siempre aparecen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe aclarar que este `div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"` no lo tengo en mi HTML del componente, sino que aparece automáticamente cada vez que recargo o guardo algún cambio en mi proyecto, de hecho solo tengo esto en el HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Habrá alguna forma de quitarlas solo en este apartado del `carousel-caption`?

Comment: Esa etiqueta que utilizas `shop-carousel-items` suena a esta libreria: [Angular Shop UI Library](https://anartz-mugika.gitbook.io/angular-shop-ui-library/).  Debes preguntarles a ellos pues cualquier cosa que te digamos aquí para sobreescribir esos valores podria ser revertida en posteriores actualizaciones de su código. Además, aqui no damos soporte a librerias de terceros, lo siento.

Comment: Otra forma de poderlo solucionar, sin tener que tocar su libreria, podria ser mediante el uso de javascript directo (o jquery) buscando todos los elementos que tengan carousel-caption entre sus clases y forzar la eliminación de las que no deseas. No conozco angular y no se como implementar javascript puro o jquery en el, ni tampoco tengo claro si esos elementos que usan carousel-caption son cargados dinámicamente o bien durante la carga del documento, lo cual podria dificultar la implementación de esta solución.  Ahí lo dejo. Suerte

Comment: Chequea [este](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/angular/add-class-to-an-element-in-angular-4/) artículo, quizá te sea de utilidad. Exitos

Comment: Hasta el momento he sobreescrito las clases .d-md-block y d-none en el CSS y me puse en contacto con el desarrollador de la librería a ver si me puede dar alguna opción. Saludos!